# Applescript for Reminders + Mail linked together

Tags: macos, applescript

On macOS and iOS, one can create reminders (in Reminders.app) from Mail.app such that when the Mail icon is clicked (or tapped on an iPhone), the source email opens in Mail.app, without further ado.

For instance, in this [(attached image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnAWP.png), I'd simply have to click on the icon on the far right to open the source email in Mail.app.

I am looking for a way to programmatically achieve this behavior using applescript. I tried setting the reminder url using "message:" and while that works on the MBP, it doesn't work on the iPhone.

Any help appreciated.